# Convert a tensor from 128,128,3 to 129,128,3 and the 1,128,3 values padded to that tensor happens later

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

This is my piece of code for GAN where the model is being initialized, everything is working and only the relevant code to the problem is present here:

```
z = Input(shape=(100+384,))
img = self.generator(z)
print("before: ",img)    #128x128x3 shape, dtype=tf.float32
temp = tf.get_variable("temp", [1, 128, 3],dtype=tf.float32)
img=tf.concat(img,temp)
print("after: ",img)    #error ValueError: Incompatible type conversion requested to type 'int32' for variable of type 'float32_ref'
valid = self.discriminator(img)
self.combined = Model(z, valid)
```

I have 128x128x3 images to generate, what I want to do is give 129x128x3 images to discriminator and the 1x128x3 text-embedding matrix is concatenated with the image while training. But I have to specify at the start the shape of tensors and input value that each model i.e. GEN and DISC will get. Gen takes 100noise+384embedding matrix and generates 128x128x3 image which is again embeded by some embedding i.e. 1x128x3 and is fed to DISC. So my question is that whether this approach is correct or not? Also, if it is correct or it makes sense then how can I specific the stuff needed at the start so that it does not give me errors like incompatible shape because at the start I have to add these lines:-

```
    z = Input(shape=(100+384,))
    img = self.generator(z)    #128x128x3
    valid = self.discriminator(img)   #should be 129x128x3
    self.combined = Model(z, valid)
```

But img is of 128x128x3 and is later during training changed to 129x128x3 by concatenating embedding matrix. So how can I change "img" from 128,128,3 to 129,128,3 in the above code either by padding or appending another tensor or by simply reshaping which of course is not possible. Any help will be much much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) should be the list of tensors, while the second is the axis along which to concatenate. You could concatenate the `img` and `temp` tensors as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.ones(shape=(128, 128, 3))
temp = tf.get_variable("temp", [1, 128, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
img = tf.concat([img, temp], axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.shape(img)))
```

---

**UPDATE:** Here you have a minimal example showing why you get the error "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'". This error pops up in the following snippet:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf

img = Input(shape=(128, 128, 3))  # Shape=(batch_size, 128, 128, 3)
temp = Input(shape=(1, 128, 3))  # Shape=(batch_size, 1, 128, 3)
concat = tf.concat([img, temp], axis=1)
print(concat.get_shape())
dense = Dense(1)(concat)
model = Model(inputs=[img, temp], outputs=dense)
```

This happens because tensor `concat`is not a Keras tensor, and therefore some of the typical Keras tensors' attributes (such as `_keras_history`) are missing. To overcome this problem, you need to encapsulate all TensorFlow tensors into a Keras [Lambda layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda):

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf

img = Input(shape=(128, 128, 3))  # Shape=(batch_size, 128, 128, 3)
temp = Input(shape=(1, 128, 3))  # Shape=(batch_size, 1, 128, 3)
concat = Lambda(lambda x: tf.concat([x[0], x[1]], axis=1))([img, temp])
print(concat.get_shape())
dense = Dense(1)(concat)
model = Model(inputs=[img, temp], outputs=dense)
```

Comment: Although it did solve my issue but I am still getting error "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'" which I believe after googling is because of a var temp that is of tf and all others are of keras and so it isn't working.

Comment: You get this error because you need to encapsulate all the TensorFlow operations into a Keras Lambda layer (see https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda)

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate a little bit more? How can I use it here in this code, maybe a minimal example please.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it. Also "self.combined = Model(z, valid)" will come after the updated code snippet?

Comment: I am not entire sure about what is your architecture exactly, but I guess so