# Give a list and an image as input to a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, keras

I want to give an image and a list to a keras model for a GAN. The discriminator will get image and some list both are of fixed size i.e. 128x128x3 and 384 and the generator will produce images of 128x128x3 that the disc has to mark fake. So the problem is that I can't figure out what should be the input shape for the discriminator and how it should be initialized. Here is the most relevant initializer simple code which needs to be changed to get an image and list as input where disc gets just a 128x128x3 image and it all works fine:-

```
arr=embeddings   #384 length long list
self.generator = self.build_generator()
z = Input(shape=(100,))
img = self.generator(z)  #gen gets noise and generates 128x128x3
self.discriminator.trainable = False
valid = self.discriminator(img)  #should get 128x128x3 image and "arr" list
self.combined = Model(z, valid)
self.combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

And the training code is like this which should be changed accordingly:-

```
d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(pics, valid)
d_loss_fake = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_pics, fake)
d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)
g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(latent_code, valid)
```

The disc architecture is like this, its input layer should be changed like this that it can take a list as well with the image:-

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=5, strides=2, input_shape=(128,128,3), padding="same"))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(48, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
img = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
validity = model(img)
return Model(img, validity)
```

I did try adding the embedding with the image but then the GEN has to generate the embedding also with the image or GEN generates image and embeddings are merged to that image made of 129x128x3 and fed to DISC but then during initialize here "g_loss=self.combined.train_on_batch(latent_code, valid)" error occurs because I have to specify the shape of img at the start of 129,128,3 and more details can be found in this question by me which is related to same issue:-

[Issue when embeddings are added to the img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186451/convert-a-tensor-from-128-128-3-to-129-128-3-and-the-1-128-3-values-padded-to-th/51187464#51187464)

Any help will be great, I have been scratching my head on it for days.

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: I can't check the code that you have given right now but this question was posted earlier and till then the keras.backend error occurred.

Comment: Ok, let me know if the answer is the same, and I will move it here

Comment: okay, will check it ASAP

Comment: This is the error I am getting with that updated code "Model inputs must come from a Keras Input layer, they cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to "model_3" was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer model_2.
Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = Input(shape)`."
Can you please look at the above code and tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I can't tell from the code above. Would it be possible to provide a MCVE? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have changed my architecture and here I got an issue in that and can you kindly give it a quick look and tell me what I am doing wrong? Also I have provided a MCVE.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211443/runtime-error-disconnected-graph-for-gans-because-input-cant-be-obtained

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix I can think of is appending the same embedding  to the generator output before feeding it to the discriminator input and loss computation.

Comment: I did exactly like that and kindly see the question link posted. An issue occurs while doing so.